# dynamically check membership swi-prolog

Tags: dynamic, prolog, membership

Given a list of natural numbers `List` I want to check if the sums of the elements of each subset are distinct. Initially I used this code

```
distinctSubsetSums(List,Sums) :- findall(Sum,(subset(Sub,List),sum_list(Sub,Sum)),Sums), all_distinct(Sums).
```

But I think there exists a better solution since with my code I found all the sums of all the possibile subsets and then I check if they are distinct. I think there is a way to check dynamically if a sum has been already calculated and then return `false` without searching for all the subsets.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What result are you getting with this code? Does it work? What do you mean by "better" when you say you think there is a "better" solution?
 `all_distinct/1` only works in a CLP(FD)` context. Check the documentation. It establishes a *constraint* that all the elements of a list are distinct. It doesn't pass or fail depending upon whether elements of a list are distinct. So if what you have really isn't working, write your own `all_different/1` predicate for a list.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `clpfd` library and the code works. Using `?- trace.` I tried to look what happens with this list `[3,2,1]`. The subsets of which the sum is calculated are, in order, `[3,2,1]`,`[3,2]`,`[3,1]`,`[3]`,`[2, 1]`,`[2]`,`[1]` and `[]`, giving this sums `[6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]`. Only then it checks if this list has distinct elements, failing since it contains two `3`. What I want is to check duplicate items while searching, so that the predicate fails at the fifth subset found (`[2,1]` will give a sum of `3` like `[3]` does).

Comment: You can write a recursive predicate that takes the list of subsets, plus a list of the sums so far. On each call you calculate the sum for the current subset and check that it is not in the list. At the end you have the list of unique sums.

Comment: Then you can look at interleaving the summing and checking with the generation of the subsets, so that you have only one predicate.

Comment: You say I have to find all the subsets before finding the sums? What I want is find a subset -> calculate the sum -> check if it's a duplicate -> if yes, fail. if not, find the next subset and restart

Comment: Yes, that was my 2nd version. You can start with the `subset/2` predicate shown in the other question, add the list of sums, and then in the base case you do the summing and comparison of the current subset.

Comment: Well, you would need to change so that the result is passed down to the base case rather than built up back to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subset_sums(List,Sums) :-
  sum_subset(List,[],[],Sums).

sum_subset([I|Is],Js,Sums0,Sums) :-
  sum_subset(Is,Js,Sums0,Sums1),
  sum_subset(Is,[I|Js],Sums1,Sums).
sum_subset([],Js,Sums0,Sums) :-
  sum_list(Js,Sum),
  \+ member(Sum,Sums0),
  Sums = [Sum|Sums0].
```